# how to apply a capping in a dataframe to distribute percentages evenly when the cap has reached

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below. I want to apply a capping factor so when 15% weights is reached the excess weight is distrusted evenly across. Can someone help me? I am still new to python and struggling with this, thanks!

```
            Weights %
TICKER  
XXX US Equity   1.185202
YYY US Equity   1.449595
QQQ US Equity   2.582312
EEE US Equity   3.900307
RRR US Equity   10.467625
YYYY US Equity  11.200174
RRRR US Equity  14.001746
WSDE CN Equity  18.021638
SDE US Equity   18.479187
AWE US Equity   18.712215
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: the weights which are above 15% would be distributed evenly so for example the weight of AWE US Equity will be 15% and the excess 3.71% would go to XXX US equity and YYY US equity etc

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. We ask that users provide a [mcve], including both sample input and output, as well as what you've tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you're trying to accomplish.

However, I needed to run through the logic twice, since once you add the "stuff above 15" it pushes one of the smaller values above 15. If the size of your data is an issue, you can just put the few lines of code into a `while` loop that will stop once everything is 15 or under.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ticker = ['XXX US Equity', 'YYY US Equity', 'QQQ US Equity', 'EEE US Equity', 'RRR US Equity', 'YYYY US Equity', 'RRRR US Equity', 'WSDE CN Equity', 'SDE US Equity', 'AWE US Equity']
weights_percent = [1.185202, 1.449595, 2.582312, 3.900307, 10.467625, 11.200174, 14.001746, 18.021638, 18.479187, 18.712215]

dat = pd.DataFrame({'ticker': ticker, 'weights_percent': weights_percent})

# Create new column to see what rows need to change

dat['new_weights_percent'] = dat.weights_percent - 15
dat['new_weights_percent'] = np.where(dat.new_weights_percent < 0, 0, dat.new_weights_percent)

# Get amount to add to remaining
all_weights = dat.new_weights_percent.sum()
avg_to_apply_to_remaining = all_weights/sum(dat.new_weights_percent == 0)

# Add this amount to reminaing and "floor" the others at 15
dat['weights_percent'] = np.where(dat.weights_percent < 15, dat.weights_percent + avg_to_apply_to_remaining, 15)


# Need to do the whole thing twice, since there's a value that gets to be above 15 after you add the remainder

dat['new_weights_percent'] = dat.weights_percent - 15
dat['new_weights_percent'] = np.where(dat.new_weights_percent < 0, 0, dat.new_weights_percent)

# Get amount to add to remaining
all_weights = dat.new_weights_percent.sum()
avg_to_apply_to_remaining = all_weights/sum(dat.new_weights_percent == 0)

# Add this amount to reminaing and "floor" the others at 15
dat['weights_percent'] = np.where(dat.weights_percent < 15, dat.weights_percent + avg_to_apply_to_remaining, 15)


dat.drop(columns=['new_weights_percent'], inplace=True)


print(dat)
```

### Output:

```
           ticker  weights_percent
0   XXX US Equity         2.695402
1   YYY US Equity         2.959795
2   QQQ US Equity         4.092512
3   EEE US Equity         5.410507
4   RRR US Equity        11.977825
5  YYYY US Equity        12.710374
6  RRRR US Equity        15.000000
7  WSDE CN Equity        15.000000
8   SDE US Equity        15.000000
9   AWE US Equity        15.000000
```

Comment: quick question would you put the whole code in a while loop as specficy dat['weights_percent'] > 15?

Comment: make a variable like max_weights = dat['weights_percent'].max() and have while max_weights > 15 as the condition